# Перегрузка операции "*" для функции Perimetr

Tags: c++, классы

У меня есть задача. Мне нужно разработать дружественную функцию Perimetr, которая вычисляет периметр пирамиды по формуле P = (2*Sb)/a
Я создал функцию Perimetr, которая, вроде как, должна решать эту задачу. Но как перегрузить оператор "*" для неё?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int counter = 1; // счетчик. Для форматированного вывода экземпляров
class Pyramid {
    friend double Perimetr(Pyramid& Sb, Pyramid& a);
public:
    double x, h, a; // x - сторона основания, h - высота, a - апофема
    Pyramid() {
        cout << endl << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "Этот обьект был создан в конструкторе по умолчанию. Область: " << this << endl;
        x = h = a = 0;
    }
    Pyramid(double p, double k, double q) {
        cout << endl << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "Этот обьект был создан в конструкторе с параметрами. Область: " << this << endl;
        x = p;
        h = k;
        a = q;
    }
    Pyramid(Pyramid& obj) {
        cout << endl << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "Этот обьект был создан в конструкторе копирования. Область: " << this << endl;
        this->x = obj.x;
        this->h = obj.h;
        this->a = obj.a;
    }
    void SHOW() {
        cout << endl << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "  p" << counter << "\tx --> " << x << ";\th --> " << h << ";\ta --> " << a << endl;
    }
    ~Pyramid() {
        cout << endl << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "Удаление объекта в области " << this << " деструктором.\n";
    }
private:
    double Sb = 10;
};

// перегружаю оператор потокового вывода
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Pyramid& pyramid) {
    os << pyramid.x << " " << pyramid.h << " " << pyramid.a;
    return os;
}

// перегружаю оператор потокового ввода
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Pyramid& pyramid) {
    is >> pyramid.x >> pyramid.h >> pyramid.a;
    return is;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(0, "");
    Pyramid p1, p2(2, 4, 6);
    p1.SHOW(); counter++;
    p2.SHOW(); counter++;

    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("1.txt");
    fout << p1;
    fout.close();
    cout << endl << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "\tДанные про первый экземпляр класса Pyramid записаны в файл 1.txt";
    cout << endl << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl;

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("1.txt");
    fin >> p2;
    fin.close();
    cout << endl << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "\tДанные про первый экземпляр класса Pyramid записаны в поля второго объекта.";
    cout << endl << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl;

    counter = 2;
    p2.SHOW();

    return 0;
}

double Perimetr(Pyramid& Sb, Pyramid& a)
{   
    return (2*Sb)/a;
}
```

Ошибки:

```
1) E0349    отсутствует оператор "*", соответствующий этим операндам
2) C2677    бинарный "*": не найден глобальный оператор, принимающий тип "Pyramid" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)
```

Comment: А зачем его перегружать?

Comment: @Эникейщик, если попробовать скомпилировать - будет ошибка. Связана она с тем, что компилятор не видет перегрузки для этой операции "*"

Comment: Так зачем перегружать этот оператор?

Comment: @Эникейщик, ну, типа, чтобы исправить ошибку.
Возможно, я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: Наверняка. Какая ошибка-то?

Comment: @Эникейщик, дополнил вопрос

Comment: Так периметр считается по длине сторон (т.е. просто числа), а не по объектам Pyramid.

Comment: @Эникейщик, да, Вы правы.
Просто у меня была задача: сделать дружественную функцию, которая будет считать периметр. 
Мне показалось, что ожидается что-то в этом духе. Получается, что неправ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну так объявление этой функции (приведу ещё раз тут)

```cpp
friend double Perimetr(Pyramid& Sb, Pyramid& a);
```

Гласит о том, что эта функция принимает две ссылки на объекты типа `Pyramid`. Я так понимаю, ты считаешь, что она принимает ссылки на **поля** класса `Pyramid` с именами `Sb` и `a`, но это не так :)

Суть в том, что надо принимать лишь один экземпляр класса, а внутри функции работать с его полями:

```cpp
//
// Не сказать бы, что транслитное название хорошее...
// Лучше к такому не привыкать.
//
friend double Perimetr(
    /* В самом объекте ничего не меняешь - лучше принимать по ссылке на константу */
    const Pyramid& pyramid
)
{
    return (2 * pyramid.Sb) / pyramid.a;
}
```

PS. Лучше вот эти поля тоже в `private` поместить:

```cpp
double x, h, a;
```